# SQL Lite DELETE Query not working

Tags: android, sqlite

SQLite delete query isn't working. Can anyone tell me how to use `db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs)` method in limit query?!

```
String query = "DELETE From gpsinfo  LIMIT 100 ";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Comment: use [db.execSQL(ur_sql_query)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String))

Comment: try `String query = "DELETE From gpsinfo where ID= ur_id LIMIT 100 ;";`

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
Delete from table_name where ID IN (Select ID from table_name limit 100 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `execSQL()` for SQL like this.

`rawQuery()` doesn't run the SQL until you move the returned cursor.

Also, you cannot use `LIMIT` like this.

Comment: You *can* use LIMIT, but not with SQLite's default configuration, which is all you get in Android.

Answer (score -1):

String query = "DELETE FROM " +TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "  + COLUMN_NAME+ " = " + "'"+text+"'" ;

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(query);

    db.close();
```